# azure data factory copy activity failing DUE TO COLUMN MISMATCH

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am performing copy activity in ADF with source as csv file in gen1. which's copied to sql server. i am getting the below error. i thoroughly checked each column .count is matching.

Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'opportunity.csv' with row number 224: found more columns than expected column count 136

Comment: Could you please add your csv schema and sql schema?

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems you have a column delimiter value within your data itself.

Comment: @Nandan yes i have ',' in my data itself. i tried giving other delimiters, its not wrking

Comment: There are 2 ways : either make your make delimiter  unique (you can create a dual delimiter like ^| or use quote characters